# Finding the c.d.f.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two equal rods each of length $2a$ are broken into two parts at points whose positions are random. $X$ is the length of the shortest of the four parts thus obtained. Find the probability, $F(x)$, that $X\leqslant x$ where $0<x\leqslant a$.

The answer is $$F(x)=1-\left(\frac{a-x}a\right)^2$$ but I'm unsure as to how I'd obtain this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- Denoting the shortests parts of rods $1$ and $2$ by $X_1$ and $X_2$ we have: $$X>x\iff X_1>x\wedge X_2>x$$
- If $U_i$ stands for the 'breakpoint' of rod $i$ then it has uniform distribution over $[0,2a]$ and $X_i$ takes values in $[0,a]$  with: $$X_i>x\iff x<U_i<2a-x$$

Comment: Ah so X=<x iff X_1=<x OR X_2=<x. P(X_1=<x OR X_2=<x) = 1 - P(X_1>x)P(X_2>x), where clearly P(X_i>x) =1-INT (0 to x) 1/a du = (a-x)/a. Then the result immediately follows. Thanks.

Comment: The idea is okay but: $P(X_i>x)=\frac1{2a}\int_{x}^{2a-x}du=\frac{2a-2x}{2a}=\frac{a-x}{a}$ (same outcome). Note that $U$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,2a]$ and its PDF is constant function $\frac1{2a}$.